# How to get rid of trash?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In Animal Crossing on Gamecube, you were able to throw boots, cans, etc away at the dump.  The dump was a fenced in area where you could throw away trash that was collected as well as obtain free items.

In New Leaf, the only way I've seen to throw items away is to pay for their disposal at Re-Tail.

Is there anything similar to the original dump in New Leaf that allows for me to throw stuff away for free and/or collect free items every day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options when it comes to trash. First, like you have noticed, you can take it to Re-Tail, who will recycle it for a fee.

There are also a couple of different furniture items that are garbage cans, so if you have one of those, you can also put it in there to dispose of it for free.

A third option is to make the garbage can public works project, which works in the same way as the garbage can furniture items.

However, if you really want to make sure that your town stays pristine and free of trash, if you enact the Keep Town Beautiful town ordinance, it will keep your town free of trash and weeds!

Comment: Are there pre-reqs to the garbage can works project?  It doesn't show up for me.

Comment: Yeah, you need one of your neighbours to approach you and suggest it, so it is pretty random.